# Compiler not checking type parameter bounds?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface defining the following method:

```
public <C extends RTSpan<V>, V extends Object> void onEffectSelected(Effect<V, C> effect, V value);
```

I'm calling this like this:

```
mListener.onEffectSelected(Effects.BOLD, true);
```

with `Effects.BOLD` being an `Effect<Boolean,RTSpan<Boolean>>` object.

I was under the impression that the compiler should make sure that the two Vs in the `onEffectSelected` are of the same type?

However if I write:

```
mListener.onEffectSelected(Effects.BOLD, 1);
```

It compiles without issues and of course throws a runtime exception.

What's wrong here? How can I make sure that the second parameter has an identical type to the one used in the first parameter?

**EDIT**

```
public class GenericsTest {
    interface RTSpan<V> {}
    static class BoldSpan implements RTSpan<Boolean> {}

    static class Effect<V extends Object, C extends RTSpan<V>> {}
    static class BoldEffect extends Effect<Boolean, BoldSpan> {}

    interface TheListener {
        public <C extends RTSpan<V>, V extends Object> void onEffectSelected(Effect<V, C> effect, V value);
    }

    static class Effects {
        public static final Effect BOLD = new BoldEffect();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TheListener listener = new TheListener() {
            @Override
            public <C extends RTSpan<V>, V> void onEffectSelected(Effect<V, C> effect, V value) {}
        };

        listener.onEffectSelected(Effects.BOLD, Boolean.TRUE);
        listener.onEffectSelected(Effects.BOLD, 1);     // this compiles
        listener.onEffectSelected(new BoldEffect(), 1); // this doesn't compile
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be Effects.BOLD. If I replace it with a new BoldEffect() the compiler complains. Does anyone know why the static instantiation throws off the compiler?

Comment: Could you post a full but minimal working example?

Comment: Not sure if that would help. I'm assuming a part answer to my question is that both parameters are checked independently and both are correct (meeting the V extends Object bounds) so I guess the question is more how to make sure that the compiler checks whether the two Vs are identical.

Comment: I don't think you need the V extends Object, and that might be what's causing issues. Can you try public <C extends RTSpan<V>, V> void onEffectSelected(onEffectSelected(Effect<V, C> effect, V value);

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: I used my close vote, but here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Close vote because "does not appear to be about programming". Haven't laughed that much for a long time... And what does a question about "What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?" have to do with this?

Comment: No, I voted to close as unreproducible (more specifically), now retracted. Your `BOLD` field is of the raw type `Effect`. That has the effect (no pun intended) of erasing all generics in the method you use it with. The link explains all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static final Effect BOLD = new BoldEffect();
```

This use of raw types essentially turns off type checking entirely anywhere `BOLD` is used.  Turn it into `Effect<Boolean, BoldSpan>` and type checking will work properly.